# How to identify component name from a object array

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-props

Currently I have the following

```
methodName = () => {
  const {
    collectionOfComponents
    ...
    ...
  } = this.props;

  return (
    <Wrapper1>
      {collectionOfComponents.map((oneComponent, index) => (
        <Wrapper2
          ..props
        >
          {oneComponent.component}
        </Wrapper2>
      )}
    </Wrapper1>
  );
};
```

And for collectionOfComponents I am passing in the following

```
collectionOfComponents={[
<ComponentOne prop1... prop2... />,
<ComponentOne prop1... prop2... />,
<ComponentTwo prop1... prop2... />
]}
```

Is there a way to identify when `ComponentTwo` has been passed through so that I can perform a different render. I'm not sure how to do this

EDIT
Sorry, should of made this clear, but i'm not looking to change the render method in the map i'm looking for a separate function to first check to see if `componentTwo` exists in the array at any time and then (maybe) use a tertiary to call one of two methods which will be two different return methods. I will then call the function in the render method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const isComponentTwo = collectionOfComponents.some(component => component.type.displayName.includes('ComponentTwo'));
```

The above will return true if at least one component in the collectionOfComponents is `ComponentTwo`.

This is not advisable however. Using `displayName` or `type` for production should never be used. This is because during, for example, minification the `displayName` and `type` will change, so the logic you are expecting will not occur in the way you are expecting.

The [following](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#displayname) states:

> The displayName string is used in debugging messages. Usually, you don’t need to set it explicitly because it’s inferred from the name of the function or class that defines the component. You might want to set it explicitly if you want to display a different name for debugging purposes or when you create a higher-order component

A better solution would be to add some sort of `flagProp` to your component.
For example

```
decideWhatToDo = () => {
  const { flagPropName } = this.props;
  return flagPropName
    ? this.methodOne()
    : this.methodTwo();
 }
```

In the two methods you can then decide what you want to do if `componentTwo` exists or if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

When you use a component, React creates an [Element](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html#elements-describe-the-tree). Each element has a `type` property. The type is the class of function for [component elements](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html#component-elements), or a string for [DOM elements](https://reactjs.org/blog/2015/12/18/react-components-elements-and-instances.html#dom-elements) ('button').

To find the component that created the element, compare the type of the element to the Function of Class that created it:

```js
const ComponentOne = () => 1;
const ComponentTwo = () => 2;
class ComponentThree extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return 3;
  }
}

const Wrapper = ({ children }) => (
  <div>
  {React.Children.map(children, (El) => {
    switch(El.type) {
      case ComponentOne:
        return <div className="red">{El}</div>;
      case ComponentTwo:
        return <div className="blue">{El}</div>;
      case ComponentThree:
        return <div className="green">{El}</div>;
    }
    
    return null;
  })}
  </div>
);

ReactDOM.render(
  <Wrapper>
    <ComponentOne />
    <ComponentOne />
    <ComponentTwo />
    <ComponentThree />
  </Wrapper>,
  demo
);
```

```css
.red { background: red; }
.blue { background: blue; }
.green { background: green; }
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="demo"></div>
```

Comment: or in the case of needing to compare against strings (for whatever reason) `El.type.name`.

Comment: You should note that functions' and classes' names might change after minification.

Comment: Is there a way to check if componentTwo exists in a separate function and then decide what to do? e.g. call one function if componentTwo exists, if not call another?

Comment: Do whatever you want in the switch. I've returned the element, you call a function that will return something else.

Answer (score -1):

Check in the array using indexOf:

```
collectionOfComponents.indexOf('ComponentTwo') !== -1 // found
```

Comment: Components will not be unique there could be 5 `ComponentOne` and two `ComponentTwo` or there could be 7`ComponentTwo` and 1 `ComponentOne`

Comment: Anyways, you are just wondering if that component is found, right?

Comment: Let me  know if you have any query.

Answer (score -1):

Maybe you can use this way or simulary ??

```
    <Wrapper1>
      {collectionOfComponents.map((oneComponent, index) => (
        <Wrapper2
          ..props
        >
          {oneComponent.component instanceof ComponentTwo ? renderWasYouWant : otherRender }
        </Wrapper2>
      )
    </Wrapper1>
```